# rake undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I'm hoping there is someone out here with a few encouraging words and a little advice.

I am using Ruby v1.9.2 p290

I've been setting up a new production server and I'm having a terrible time trying to get the new environment to work correctly. Everything is installed and now I'm trying to run `rake`, but it is giving me an error I can't make any sense of and can't find any internet help on.

```
deploy@ip-10-99-66-30:~/pm$ rake -v --trace
rake aborted!
undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `rescue in rescue in block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `rescue in block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
/home/deploy/pm/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/home/deploy/pm/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `block in run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Here is my gem list

```
actionmailer (3.1.0)
actionpack (3.1.0)
activemodel (3.1.0)
activerecord (3.1.0)
activeresource (3.1.0)
activesupport (3.1.0)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
arel (2.2.3)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.1.4)
cancan (1.6.8)
capybara (1.1.2)
childprocess (0.3.3)
client_side_validations (3.1.4)
cocaine (0.2.1)
coffee-rails (3.1.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
columnize (0.3.6)
cucumber (1.2.1)
cucumber-rails (1.3.0)
daemon_controller (1.0.0)
database_cleaner (0.8.0)
devise (1.5.3)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
factory_girl (3.5.0)
factory_girl_rails (3.5.0)
faker (1.0.1)
fastthread (1.0.7)
ffi (1.0.11)
geocoder (1.1.2)
gherkin (2.11.1)
guard (1.2.3)
guard-rspec (1.2.0)
haml (3.1.6)
haml-rails (0.3.4)
hike (1.2.1)
hpricot (0.8.6)
httparty (0.8.3)
i18n (0.6.0)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (1.0.19)
json (1.7.3)
json_pure (1.7.3)
jsonify (0.3.1)
jsonify-rails (0.3.2)
libv8 (3.3.10.4 x86_64-linux)
linecache19 (0.5.12)
listen (0.4.7)
mail (2.3.3)
meta_search (1.1.3)
mime-types (1.19)
minitest (1.6.0)
multi_json (1.3.6)
multi_xml (0.5.1)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
nokogiri (1.5.5)
orm_adapter (0.0.7)
paperclip (2.7.0)
passenger (3.0.17)
polyamorous (0.5.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.3.6)
rack-cache (1.0.3)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.1.0)
rails3-jquery-autocomplete (1.0.7)
railties (3.1.0)
rake (0.9.2)
rb-fchange (0.0.5)
rb-fsevent (0.9.1)
rb-inotify (0.8.8)
rdoc (3.12, 2.5.8)
remotipart (1.0.2)
rspec (2.11.0)
rspec-core (2.11.1)
rspec-expectations (2.11.3)
rspec-mocks (2.11.2)
rspec-rails (2.11.0)
ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25)
ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
ruby_parser (2.3.1)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
sass (3.1.20)
sass-rails (3.1.4)
selenium-webdriver (2.7.0)
sexp_processor (3.2.0)
simple_datatables (0.2.1)
sprockets (2.0.4)
therubyracer (0.10.1)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
timeliness (0.3.6)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
uglifier (1.2.6)
validates_timeliness (3.0.12)
warden (1.2.1)
web-app-theme (0.8.0)
webrat (0.7.3)
will_paginate (3.0.3)
xpath (0.1.4)
```

I've spent several days on this, not much hair left on my head after all the hair pulling.

Any suggestions? Ruby on Rails is an excellent platform to work with, but I'm stumped on this one.

Comment: what version of ruby and rubygems are you running on the server? did you try setting up rvm or rbenv so that you can make sure it's not a broken system-ruby?

Comment: I'm using Ruby 1.9.2p290. I have not setup rvm because I've read that is not a good idea for a production server. Is that idea bogus?

Comment: there is no good reason not to use rvm or rbenv on your production server.

Comment: Can you run irb successfully?

Comment: irb seems to startup without any problems.

Comment: I might have to backup and go the rvm route.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the bundler gem to the latest version (1.2.3 at the time of answering) by doing:

```
gem update bundler
```

fixed this problem for me. Well, it didn't exactly fix it but it allowed the actual error message that was causing the problem to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with my gem .

update the bundler

Read the error properly, it will tell you which gem is the culprit.

Thing is that not all gems are compatible with OS .

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue related to gem versions clashing and bundler spitting out a particularly opaque error message.

See:
https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1847

Apparently this was patched in a recent version of bundler. I have the same issue at present and am looking into it but I hope this helps point you in the right direction.